# Python Tkinter: Reading in file from location, creating checkbuttons for each file

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to read in text files from a folder location on my pc. Then create checkbuttons for each file. After making a checkbutton selection, I want to press 'Submit' to print each file selected in the console window.

```
from Tkinter import *
#Tk()
import os
root = Tk()

v = StringVar()
v.set("null")  # initializing the choice, i.e. Python

def ShowChoice():
state = v
if state != 0:
     print(file)


for file in os.listdir("Path"):
if file.endswith(".txt"):
        aCheckButton = Checkbutton(root, text=file, variable= file)
        aCheckButton.pack(anchor =W)
        v = file
        print (v) 


submitButton = Button(root, text="Submit", command=ShowChoice)
submitButton.pack()


mainloop()
```

After running this code, the result is that when any check buttons are checked and submit button selected, only the last text file in the folder is printed. It makes sense to me why this is, because the file is being saved as the last file which was read in. However, I can't think of a way to store each file name. Unless maybe I read files into an array which I'm not sure how to do either. 
Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> Unless maybe I read files into an array

No, you do not want to read all of those files at once.  That will greatly impact performance.

But it would be good if you made a list of the checkbuttons and their associated variables.  That way, you can easily access them inside the function `ShowChoice`.

Below is a version of your program that adopts this idea.  I commented most of the lines I changed:

```
from Tkinter import *
import os
root = Tk()

# A list to hold the checkbuttons and their associated variables
buttons = []

def ShowChoice():
    # Go through the list of checkbuttons and get each button/variable pair
    for button, var in buttons:
        # If var.get() is True, the checkbutton was clicked
        if var.get():
            # So, we open the file with a context manager
            with open(os.path.join("Path", button["text"])) as file:
                # And print its contents
                print file.read()


for file in os.listdir("Path"):
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        # Create a variable for the following checkbutton
        var = IntVar()
        # Create the checkbutton
        button = Checkbutton(root, text=file, variable=var)
        button.pack(anchor=W)            
        # Add a tuple of (button, var) to the list buttons
        buttons.append((button, var))


submitButton = Button(root, text="Submit", command=ShowChoice)
submitButton.pack()

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the checkbutton doc](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/checkbutton.htm), you have to bind a IntVar to the button, to query its state.

So while building buttons, give them an IntVar, cheat and attach the filename to the IntVar so get it later:

```
checked = IntVar()
checked.attached_file = file
aCheckButton = Checkbutton(root, text=file, variable=checked)
aCheckButton.pack(anchor=W)
buttons.append(checked)
```

Your ShowChoice now looks like:

```
def ShowChoice():
    print [button.attached_file for button in buttons if button.get()]
```

Printing the attached file (button.attached_file) for each button if the button is checked (button.get() is 1 if checked).

Don't forgot to declare a "buttons = []" before all this stuff.

You also may read and adopt the [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for the style, to end with a more readable (for everybody) file.